# R data structure for large number of users with large number of values

Tags: arraylist, multidimensional-array, data-structures, nsmutablearray, arrayofarrays

Please, i need an advise to build up my program. I have a large number of users, for example, 100 users. For each user, there is an array of 144 columns and 11 rows ( 1584 values ). I need the best data structure that enables me from easily access and change to all (1584 values for all users). I am confused what is the best data structure to use, for instance, the array of arrays (array of users and each element is array of (1584 values), or data-fram of arrays or record of arrays.

Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It depends on what will change how, when, how often, types of data, how the data is used, which OS, …